# updating a Date object on the client side after getting the correct Date from the server side

Tags: javascript, timestamp, utc

I have a UI that needs to have the UTC time updated all the time to be shown to the users.

my original code was this:

```
(function () {
    $http.get('api/getdate').success(function (data) {
        current = new Date(data.res + new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);
        updateDateTimer = setInterval(function(){
            $http.get('api/getdate').success(function (data) {
                current = new Date(data.res + new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);
            });
        }, 30000);
    });
})();
```

data.res has the correct timestamp i need. this way works fine because i can trust my server with the data that is sent back to the UI. then the only data that i need from the user is its offset from UTC and thus i am sure the date that will be displayed will be correct.

my problem is that a call to the server will be made every 30 seconds, and if i want my clock to change even more often then this can get really nasty.

i thought about making the call to the server only one time and then add 1 second with a timer to the Date object created but this is very not accurate and after a few minutes you can see that the clock is not synchronized any more with the real time.

is there any possibly to not make more calls to the server after the first time?
the problem is that i can't make sure the client won't change its local clock. it seems i need to some how deal with the Date object that is being created with the first .get call, but how?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clarify the question a bit? If the only thing you're trying to do is find/show the **current** UTC time, new Date().getTime() returns the millis since January 1, 1970 UTC so that time is already in UTC (2 calls of getTime() occurring simultaneously in New York and Los Angeles will show the same number). Then you have some UTC functions on the Date object which give you the UTC time, like getUTCHours(), getUTCMinutes and getUTCSeconds().